# How to handle multiple material-UI Popovers [React.js]?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, material-ui

My app has multiple [Popover](https://material-ui.com/components/popover/) components, I know how to handle the state of one `Popover` component, using something like this:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { pop_open: false };
  }

  handleProfileDropDown(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.setState({
          pop_open: !this.state.pop_open,
          anchorEl: e.currentTarget,
      });
    }

  handleRequestClose() {
      this.setState({
          pop_open: false,
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button type="submit"  onClick={this.handleProfileDropDown.bind(this)} >My Customized PopOver</button>
        <Popover
            open={this.state.pop_open}
            anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
            onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose.bind(this)}
        >
            {"content"}
        </Popover>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But for more than one `Popover`, I do not know how to do that, should I create a state for each `Popover`? Sorry for the question but I am new to the frontend world.

note: kindly do not use hooks in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

An *internal state* is a good option when only the Component is going to modify it. It keeps the logic simple and inside the same block of code. On the other hand managing the *state from outside* of the Component lets other components read its values and modify them. This is a common approach when using Redux or Context, where there is a global app state. This state is meant for properties that several Components need to read/write to.

Which to use when is a design decision and **depends on each situation**. In my opinion each Component should handle its own state when possible. For example, when values are only going to be modified by it, or a children Component. Having an external state makes sense when multiple Components are going to read or modify it, or when the state values need to be passed several levels deep in the hierarchy.

In the example you propose I can see that the Popover is working with an internal state. This can work and you can use the Component several times and it will carry all the logic inside. If you rename the Components you can see more easily what I mean. I dont know exactly how the Component with the button works but this is to make the explanation clear:

```
class Popover extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { is_open: false };
    }

    open = () => {
        this.setState({
            is_open: true
        });
    }

    close = () => {
        this.setState({
            is_open: false
        });
    }

    toggle = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            is_open: !prevState.is_open
        }));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.toggle}>
                    Open
                </button>
                {this.state.is_open && <PopoverContent />}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

If you need further explanation or something is not clear, let me know.

Comment: @adnanmuttaleb Giving a look to the Component you are linking I can see that it is confusing. The way it handles the `open` value (not in a state) is dependending on the `anchorEl`, which is assigned the button HTML element when clicked and `null` when closed.